# Filling DIV height

Tags: css, footer, fill

Been trying to solve this for about an hour now and it's getting frustrating.

So I need my div to fill the rest of the page down to the footer.

http://gyazo.com/999cce47ea567878586fbc4c843f80fc

Setting height to 100% on the div doesn't increase the size at all.

```
.body-middle {
    width: 979px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom:0;
    height:100%;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
footer {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color:#ebebeb;
}
```

They are both in a div called page

```
.page {
    min-height: 100%;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: I already did, didn't change anything.

Comment: if you aren't bothered about older browsers you can add this to your `.body-middle` - `box-sizing:border-box;`

Comment: didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your body element `width:100%` too.

Answer (score 0):

In order for it to occupy the entire height of the screen, you have to add `height:100%` to both the `html` and `body` tags.

http://jsfiddle.net/WtAg7/1/

PS: Unless there are other divs that use these class names (.page, .body-middle), you should be using ID's instead, which would be connected to CSS by replacing the `.` prefix with a `#` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Set body and height styling to 100%, then set your div to 100% height.

CSS

```
body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
html { height: 100%; }
.container { height: 100%;}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<span>Something</span>
</div>
</body>
```